# react router not working on some pages on live site

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

[my live site](http://tdring.com) and [my code](https://github.com/Trishadring/Portfolio)

all my links would just fine on `npm start` but when I ran `npm run build` the routes for some pages stop working. `/about` doesn't work at all and if you are on the 404 page and navigate back the `/projects` page stops working as well.

Comment: What do you get on `/about` route?

Comment: Did you try using `Link` rather than a tags in your `nav.js` file? And also best practice while working with multiple routes is using `Switch` and enclosing all your routes within it and also use `exact` keyword in all your `Route` tags. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @RoshanKanwar After adding link the file worked again. I've tried added switch before but it causes the site to break. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `BrowserRouter` to wrap all your `Routes` in your `Nav` component and use `Link` to render `About` component as follows.

For more info: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

```
import "./nav.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import LogoS from "../imgs/logo-sm.png";
import Logo1 from "../imgs/logo-01.png";
import Projects from "./project-list";
import Aub from "./projects/auburn";
import M3d from "./projects/m3d";
import Uroute from "./projects/uroute";
import Thesis from "./projects/thesis";
import About from "./about";
import ACNH from "./projects/acnh";

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <header className="navbar">
          <div className="container">
            <Link to="/projects">
              <p className="mb-0 navbar-brand">
                <img
                  alt="Trisha Dring"
                  className="image logo d-sm-none"
                  src={LogoS}
                />
                <img
                  className="image logo d-none d-sm-block"
                  alt="Trisha Dring"
                  src={Logo1}
                />
              </p>
            </Link>
            <ul className="nav">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link
                  to="/about"
                  className="nav-link active"
                  aria-current="page"
                >
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a className="nav-link" href="/">
                  Resume
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a
                  className="nav-link"
                  href="mailto:trisha.dring+website@gmail.com"
                >
                  Contact
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
        <Route path="/projects" component={Projects} />
        <Route path="/ACNH" component={ACNH} />
        <Route path="/Auburn" component={Aub} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/M3D" component={M3d} />
        <Route path="/Uroute" component={Uroute} />
        <Route path="/FixHFA" component={Thesis} />
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Redirect to="/projects" />
        </Route>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

By the way, in your `About` component, use `className` instead of `class` as follows. Otherwise, it will give warnings.

```
<p className="explain">Hi. I'm Trisha</p>
```

Comment: You forgot to add `switch` tags

Comment: I have `BrowserRouter as Router`, and the app enclosed with `router` on the index.js page. Is it necessary to include it again?